# How to convert Lattice based signature to R1CS statements?

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, post-quantum-cryptography, fiat-shamir, dilithium

How can we convert a lattice-based signature  (like based on Fiat Shmair with abort e.g. Dilithium)  to  R1CS?